# google earth kmz file download issues

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

Im trying to download and open a kml file on goole earth but a red dot appears over a file in earth. that specific file doesn't appear on earth. I'm bad with tech, I don't know how to code or the coding language so simplified answers will be the most helpful. To find the file, search "nrdc conservation solutions layer for google earth." It is one of the first links/the first kml file that pops up. If it makes any difference I am using a mac. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please post some screenshots. We are as bad at vague descriptions as you are at tech. Also, I doubt anyone is going looking for your KML file if you can't even be bothered to post a link.

Comment: @MadPhysicist https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=nrdc+conservation+solutions+layer+for+google+earth+mac&oq=nrdc+conservation+solutions+layer+for+google+earth+mac&gs_l=serp.3...524851.526127.0.526504.4.4.0.0.0.0.154.455.2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.2.249...33i21.-53V6RJ3r_0

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I can't figure out how to post the screenshot in the comment box. However, the issue is under the places tab when you open the link in google earth. There are two folders, one named "Audubon Priority Bird Areas and Responsible Wind Development." That file has a green dot over the file icon on the left side, this is also the one that works. The other file (the one I am having issues with) is called "NRDC: Conservation Solutions for Renewable Energy in the Western US." Unlike the earlier file, this one has a red dot over the file icon on the left side and does not appear on Earth.

Comment: If the "red dot" you describe is in the list of icons in the picture below then the answer should clarify this issue.

Comment: @willis. You should not post sections of the question in the comments. Ever. All relevant information should be edited into your question. If you post the link to the screenshot, I will make it into a proper image since you do not have the rep to post images. I will also remove my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have KML with [NetworkLinks](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#networklink), the icon in the saved places (left panel) of Google Earth will reflect the state while it is fetching content. A NetworkLink links to another KML file which can a URL to a remote server.

If for example, the network link fails to open then the "error" icon with red circle will be displayed. The red circle basically means the URL failed to load content same as if it failed in a web browser. In most cases, this results from an HTTP 404 not found error that you would see in a web browser for a broken link. It could also be another 4xx code or 5xx HTTP error code. To verify the issue, right-mouse click on the NetworkLink, select "Properties", copy the URL in the link field then paste the URL into a web browser. If the target URL is broken then you'll need to fix the URL then paste back into Google Earth and/or into your KML to work correctly.

If the KML is returned to web browser but not Google Earth then the content-type (aka mime type) might be wrong. You can enable FireBug and/or the web console in your web browser to debug the HTTP response headers.

Here is the full list of icons for the state of NetworkLink from [KML 2.2 spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/kml):

[image: NetworkLink status icons]